# How does a rolled piece of paper lose its Elastic Potential Energy

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy

If you roll up a piece of paper and leave it for years it will stay rolled up. If you leave it rolled up for a minute it is easy to unroll. Of course this must be because the energy stored in that paper when it was first rolled was released in a way other than unravelling. So my question is how does a paper lose its EPE?

Comment: I think paper has very less elastic limit that's why it will stay rolled up

Comment: I have limited knowledge on EPE... elastic limit?

Comment: Elastic limit is the maximum strain produced in body from where if unloaded it will regain its orignal configuration

Comment: But having a low elastic limit doesn't answer how the energy gets released

Comment: Yes , that's why i had not answered just commented

Comment: I think the potential energy released in form of heat.For example bending a thin wire cause heating.

Comment: oh, maybe. But I don't think there is a way to know for sure for now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

paper is subject to creep: when an external load is applied, the resulting internal stresses relax slowly over time and the paper takes a *set*, meaning its original shape is  deformed. The set persists even when the external load is removed.

That deformation happens because under steady stress, the paper fibers slowly slip past one another and the deformation stresses diminish in response.

Comment: what about the EPE. Your just summing up the concept of rolling paper and it unravelling in one word

Comment: look up the mechanism of creep.

Comment: @nielsnielsen You might improve your answer with a link to it

Comment: will edit answer instead, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It should be noted that moisture greatly increases creep in paper.

Comment: yep. indeed it does.